# How to manage load balancing

Tags: load-balancing

There are `10` **servers** of a particular organization . Give some **load-balancing algorithm** for it. Also consider a case where 1 of the server takes 10 sec to process a request and other takes only 1 sec. So, how will you manage this **bottleneck**?

Comment: I have noticed the interview-questions tag. Do you need to provide an exact solution for the problem, or it's just a question to assess logical and reasoning skills?

Comment: I guess it was for assesing the logical skills but I want to know about the practical situation.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways of doing so but one of the best way is **LOAD BALANCING BY COST**.
In this type of balancing we assign a cost to each connection from client to server on the basis of the `distance` between them, policies of sub-networks between them, medium of data transmission between them etc. and after doing so we try to relocate/refer the connections to that server which gives the overall minimum cost of the connections.

Comment: of course,the `traffic` on the server is also one of the most essential factors to determine the cost of the connections.

Comment: Since, the question just provides 2 parameters in terms of processing times, I am not sure if this answer is what is expected even in the practical sense.

Answer (score 2):

May be a simple solution is: Out of every 10 tasks, assign the 1st one to the server that takes 10 sec. The next 9 tasks goes to the server that takes 1 sec.

Of course, here I assume tasks are coming in at 1 sec intervals as an assumption. With that assumption and above approach both the servers are fully utilized.